# Is there a way to break lines that match a string pattern, but only if that pattern falls between matching strings?

Tags: notepad++, regex, string

I’m using the code below to break lines that match a pattern:

**Find what:**

```
([0-9]) ([A-Z])
```

**Replace with:**  `\1\n\2`

so that …

```
Super Bowl 3,1:56.2 Armbro Goal 3,1:54.3
```

… becomes

```
Super Bowl 3,1:56.2 
Armbro Goal 3,1:54.3
```

But I have to replace each instance manually because I have tens of thousands of lines and if I use Replace All it will break lines in areas I do not want broken.

Specifically, I want to break lines that match the pattern in areas that lie between the strings “zyxl” and “1st Dam”, but not break any lines with matching patterns between “1st Dam” and “zyxl”

The following code in "Find what" will find the areas where I want lines broken:

```
(?s)^\t*zyxl(.|\r\n)*?1st Dam
```

And this code will find areas where I don’t want code broken:

```
(?s)^\t*1st Dam (.|\r\n)*?zyxl
```

Is there a way, either by combining these methods, or otherwise, to rearrange the text so that …

```
zyxl
QUEENB BLUE CHIP  
Super Bowl 3,1:56.2 Armbro Goal 3,1:54.3 Grassbed 2,1:59.1  
1st Dam 
RICHESSE OBLIGE Varenne. 13 wins, 2 thru 5. This is her first foal. 
zyxl

VENERATE 
Super Bowl 3,1:56.2 Armbro Goal 3,1:54.3 Grassbed 2,1:59.1  
1st Dam
RICHESSE OBLIGE 13 wins, 2 thru 5. This is her first foal. 
Zyxl
```

… becomes

```
zyxl
QUEENB BLUE CHIP  
Super Bowl 3,1:56.2
Armbro Goal 3,1:54.3
Grassbed 2,1:59.1  
1st Dam 
RICHESSE OBLIGE Varenne. 13 wins, 2 thru 5. This is her first foal. 
zyxl

VENERATE 
Super Bowl 3,1:56.2
Armbro Goal 3,1:54.3
Grassbed 2,1:59.1  
1st Dam 
RICHESSE OBLIGE 13 wins, 2 thru 5. This is her first foal. 
zyxl
```

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is "zyxl" before the line `VENERATE`.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:zyxl|\G)(?:(?!1st Dam).)*?\d\K\h+(?=[A-Z])`
- Replace with: `\n`  OR `\r\n` for Windows EOL
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:zyxl|\G)             # non capture group, matches zyxl or restart from last match position
(?:(?!1st Dam).)*?      # Tempered Greedy Token, make sure we don't encountered "1st Dam"
\d                      # a digit
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
\h+                     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=[A-Z])               # positive lookahead, make sure we have an uppercase after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: +1 How long did it take to write that regex?

Comment: This works perfectly.  I very much appreciate your help this week, Toto.   Beers on me (ou du vin) when I next get to Paris :)

Comment: @mapman: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Thanks. It took few minutes ;) because of experience!